# RubyMine 5.4 does not see 1.9.3 ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rubymine

Using RubyMine as my IDE for ruby development with chef on a mbp running OSX 10.8.4

Chef requires ruby 1.9 ruby, and I have it installed. When querying the ruby version via terminal it does shows : ruby 1.9.3p429 . However, when trying to use it with RubyMine, it shows (Under preferences->SDKs) only 1.8.3, not seeing or allowing me to change to 1.9.x

Any help greatly appreciated!.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried "Add SDK" next to the drop down which shows available SDKs?

Comment: Yes, but when pointing to /usr/bin/ruby, it always defaults to 1.8.3

Comment: Have you restarted RubyMine? I've got sometimes similar issue with new SDK's added from terminal.

Comment: Yes, I have.Same behaviour

Comment: Point RubyMine to the `ruby` binary that belongs to your `1.9.3p429` RVM(?) installation.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

So apparently version 1.8.3 *is* installed at /usr/bin/ruby. How did you install 1.9?

If you are using RVM then your ruby installations are probably at `~/.rvm/rubies/` instead. Or if you're using rbenv, ruby might be at `~/.rbenv`. Although RubyMine should detect the default location for [rvm](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/rvm-support.html) and [rbenv](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/rbenv-support.html). Do you have ruby in another location? Maybe check with `sudo find -name ruby` in the terminal to look for other locations of ruby.